# Using SUM in Jasper Reports Variables

Tags: mysql, sql, jasper-reports

I have a SQL query (resolved in a previous question)  that returns a a table:

```
+--------+--------+------+----------+
| ID     | Gender | Ward | Duration |
+--------+--------+------+----------+
|  43845 | Female | WD   |    26582 |
|  10519 | Female | WD   |   302777 |
|  16728 | Female | WD   |   244230 |
|  25113 | Male   | WD   |     7812 |
|  28445 | Female | WD   |  3020399 |
|  60649 | Female | WD   |    12970 |
|  81445 | Female | WD   |    13040 |
| 389760 | Female | WD   |     7757 |
|  22698 | Male   | WD   |     2399 |
| 341070 | Female | WD   |     7575 |
+--------+--------+------+----------+
```

I then have the following segments in JasperReports:

```
<variable name="WardTimeTotal" class="java.lang.String" calculation="Sum">
<variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{Duration}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>

<textField evaluationTime="Report">
<reportElement uuid="2239f376-ee94-43ce-8a33-735d9a77569e" x="226" y="90" width="292" height="30"/>
<textElement/>
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{WardTimeTotal}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

The actual data set has many 1000's of records and what is puzzling me is that the total duration does not seem to reflect the reality.  For example on one run of 70,000 records the result was 127 seconds (ultimately I need to report hours).  It occurred to me that there may be an issue with Integer size, but I am not sure how to address that.

Just wondering what I have missed here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok - silly mistake - java.lang.String should be java.lang.Long
Apologies for the hassle!